# How does AngularJS "listen" to changes in the model?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mvvm

The title is pretty much self-explicative. I would like to know how AngularJS "knows" that something changed in the model in order to update the view.

Whatever it is doing in order to achieve this. Doesn't it affect the general performance?

Comment: https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/

Answer (score 2):

> There are three phases of the life cycle of an AngularJS application
>   happen each time a web page is loaded in the browser. The following
>   sections describe these phases of an AngularJS application.
>
> **The Bootstrap Phase**
>
> The first phase of the AngularJS life cycle is the bootstrap phase,
>   which occurs when the AngularJS JavaScript library is downloaded to
>   the browser. AngularJS initializes its own necessary components and
>   then initializes your module, which the ng-app directive points to.
>   The module is loaded, and any dependencies are injected into your
>   module and made available to code within the module.
>
> **The Compilation Phase**
>
> The second phase of the AngularJS life cycle is the HTML compilation
>   stage. Initially when a web page is loaded, a static form of the DOM
>   is loaded in the browser. During the compilation phase, the static DOM
>   is replaced with a dynamic DOM that represents the AngularJS view.
>
> This phase involves two parts: traversing the static DOM and
>   collecting all the directives and then linking the directives to the
>   appropriate JavaScript functionality in the AngularJS built-in library
>   or custom directive code. The directives are combined with a scope to
>   produce the dynamic or live view.
>
> **The Runtime Data Binding Phase**
>
> The final phase of the AngularJS application is the runtime phase,
>   which exists until the user reloads or navigates away from a web page.
>   At that point, any changes in the scope are reflected in the view, and
>   any changes in the view are directly updated in the scope, making the
>   scope the single source of data for the view.
>
> AngularJS behaves differently from traditional methods of binding
>   data. Traditional methods combine a template with data received from
>   the engine and then manipulate the DOM each time the data changes.
>   AngularJS compiles the DOM only once and then links the compiled
>   template as necessary, making it much more efficient than traditional
>   methods.

Shamelessly lifted from the [Learning AngularJS](http://www.informit.com/store/learning-angularjs-9780134034546?w_ptgrevartcl=Getting%20Started%20with%20AngularJS_2271482) book by Brad Dayley.

This process is detailed in the [Scope Life Cycle](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) part of the Angular site.
 Please scroll down to 'Scope Life Cycle' section.

Answer (score 1):

William Moss gave a fantastic talk last year on Angular's $watch processes and its impact on performance. Highly recommended! See talk here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbcJfg-d5nI